# Should all classes that aren't inherited be final?

Tags: c++, c++11, final

Should I declare all classes that aren't inherited as `final` even if they don't have anything to do with inheritance and that kind of stuff?

Comment: This is essentially a question of style; valid opinions range over the entire scope of possibilities between "`final` should only be used when there is a concrete reason why subclassing a particular class would *in and of itself* be a bug" and "`final` should *always* be used, except when there is either an immediate need for a subclass, or an obvious reason why someone might want to subclass this class in the future".

Comment: `final` should probably *never* be used. I have yet to see a use case for it. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808184

Answer (score 2):

A class should be declared `final` when you want to declare the statement "this class **cannot be inherited**". This is not the same case as the statement "this class **is not inherited**". It is a matter of opinion but I would not forbid the inheritance of a class, unless there is a very specific reason to do so. Therefore, I would not declare a class `final` unless there was a reason to do so.

Hope I helped!