# Why adding final to a member function of a final class?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, final, virtual-functions

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class B {
   virtual void f() {
      std::cout << "Base" << '\n';
   }
};

class D final: public Base {
   void f() final override {
      std::cout << "Derived" << '\n';
   }
};
```

Paying attention to the two uses of the [`final`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) contextual keyword above – available since C++11 – we can observe the following:

- Adding `final` to `D`'s member function `f()` prevents `f()` from being *overridden* in a class derived from `D`.
- Adding `final` to the class `D` prevents it from further *derivation*.

Therefore, it is not possible that the member function `f()` is overridden by a class derived from `D`, since such a derived class can't exist due to the `final` applied to the class `D`.

Is there any point in using `final` as override control for a `virtual` member function of a class declared as `final`? Or is it merely redundant?

Comment: It's redundant, but this can be also seen for example when doing private inheritance, where all the members are rendered private; You still have the private keyword for some of them, but the private inheritance supersedes all.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704406/whats-the-point-of-a-final-virtual-function

Comment: "Adding final to the class D prevents it from further derivation." => " prevents it (f) from being overridden in a class derived from D". So it is redundant, no doubt.

Comment: It seems to me that is redundant, in this case. As is redundant (if I'm not wrong) using `override` together with `final`.

Comment: @max66 because `final` already implies that the member function has to be `virtual`?

Comment: I think the standard is clear, see http://eel.is/c++draft/class#4 and http://eel.is/c++draft/class.virtual#4

Comment: "because final already implies that the member function has to be virtual?" - Exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`final` on a `virtual` function in a `final` derived class is redundant.

Just like saying `virtual` on a method marked `override` is redundant. C++ just is that way sometimes.