# Virtual Final As Safety

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Consider the following:

```
class foo
{
public:
    virtual void bar() final {}
};
```

In order to prevent `bar` from being redeclared in a child class, one may use a `virtual final`. Is this a good idea? Will this come at the cost of runtime overhead, even with optimization on? What if there's already a virtual table, will its size be extended to have `bar`?

Comment: What's the point of marking a virtual method final? Why not just make it non virtual?

Comment: @AlanBirtles It can be redeclared in the child class. Doing `virtual ... final` ensures the identifier is reserved.

Comment: The OP wants to disallow providing a matching function in a derived type without making the base type itself final.

Comment: @t.niese Please note the `visual-c++` tag

Comment: Re: "To prevent [it] from being redeclared in a child class" -- what problem does this solve? Seems like a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the question since I had the same idea - so I think it's a good idea.

Answering the questions for VS 2017 (based on reading disassembly):

- No runtime overhead, even in debug-mode. Just a normal function call.
- Adds overhead of v-table (with an entry in the vtable for the function; so if you already have virtual functions the overhead is very small).
- As intended it will detect the case of someone attempting to add `void bar()` in a derived class.

One specific use case is if you are refactoring and the function was virtual and you want to remove it or make it non-virtual.

The remove-part is also found in one answer to the related (not duplicate) question: [What's the point of a final virtual function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704406/whats-the-point-of-a-final-virtual-function)

However, it seems it was not considered in:
http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rh-override
and thus you might have to justify it in code review.